# What does "You do that" mean?

Tags: meaning, sarcasm

When someone responds to something you said with "You do that.", what do they mean exactly?
Is this phrase used in a sarcastic way?
A couple of dialogue examples would be appreciated.

Comment: The response "You do that" will ***always*** refer back to the other person having announced his ***intention*** to do something. It literally means exactly what it says - the speaker is (often, *defiantly*) encouraging / permitting the other person to actually do whatever they suggested. If what they suggested was something "bad" from the speaker's perspective, it would be said defiantly. But in some other context (for example, the other person just said *I'm off to get a good night's sleep*) it might be said ***approvingly***.

Comment: ...but it's "defiant" if, say, the other person just said *If you don't go away, I'm calling the police.* Where the reply ***You do that*** would effectively mean ***Go ahead and call the police. See if I care**!* (strongly implying ***I don't care**!*).

Comment: Please provide the context in which you heard, or read, this phrase. I think there could be multiple interpretations, according to context.  It would be better if you can provide the context that you have heard this.

Comment: I'm afraid there was no specific context in mind. I just wanted to understand how and in which cases the phrase in question is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response "You do that" will **always** refer back to the other person having announced their *intention* to do something. It literally means exactly what it says - the speaker is (often, defiantly) encouraging or permitting the other person to actually do whatever they suggested.

If what they suggested was something "bad" from the speaker's perspective, it would be said defiantly. But in some other context it might be said approvingly:

> I'm sleepy. I'm going to bed now.
>
> Okay, you do that.

But it's "defiant" if, say, the other person just said something that is a threat.

> If you don't go away, I'm calling the police.
>
> You do that!

Where the reply You do that would effectively mean "Go ahead and call the police. See if I care!" (strongly implying "I don't care!")

(adapted from comments)